# Rails 3: Return large amount of data to user via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

My app has an API that users can request data. Sometimes that data takes time to process and is breaking my code.

I need a solution for this and I was thinking in using delayed_job but I'm not sure how this works. If the user makes a request, I need to give him an answer. Even if I process the data in background, the call still needs to wait until the job returns.

What is the solution for this? I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like this should definitely be handled in a background process. Check out [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) by Chris Wanstrath. I don't know the best-practice for responding once the job completes, client-side JS polling maybe? Ryan Bates just covered [Resque on Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) btw.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku has a [30 second timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), which is why your requests are failing (Probably H12 or H13 in your heroku logs).

There are three methods to work around this.

1. **Keep the connection open by sending blank data.**
   You'll need to respond within the first 30 seconds and every 55 seconds after that. Use the time in between to process the data. Sending spaces should not affect the ability of the browser to read the response.
2. **Callback**
   Have the user provide a callback URL in the initial request. When you finish processing the data, hit the callback url with your response.
3. **Polling**
   As suggested by Codeglot, you can provide the user with a key. To check on their request, they can ping your server with that key.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the user that their data is being processed and will be available shortly. Youtube, Vimeo, Facebook, Twitter, they all do this.

Comment: It's an API request, via console, how can I do that? They need the data when they request.

Comment: For a web app you could have a table that records API calls. So someone uploads a video or something and you return a key they can reference later. Cache it or make a table, then they can have javascript periodically call the api asking for that reference and get a 'still processing' message if it is not ready.

Comment: In console manually checking for a referenced API call is the only way I can think of doing it.